# Why is this a binary multi-megabyte blob `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin` under `/etc`?

Tags: linux, udev

Why is this a binary multi-megabyte blob `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin` and why under `/etc`?

Should I store it with [`etckeeper`](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/)?

Comment: I suspect, it could be same binary cache for the udev. If it is, it should be below /var/lib. I hope somebody gives a good answer, also I am curious. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`man hwdb`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hwdb.html):

> ## Hardware Database Files
>
> *-- snipping unnecessary documentation details for this answer ---*
>
> The content of all hwdb files is read by `systemd-hwdb(8)` and compiled
>   to a binary database located at `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin`, or alternatively
>   `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin` if you want ship the compiled database in an
>   immutable image. During runtime, only the binary database is used.

[`man systemd-hwdb`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-hwdb.html#):

> `systemd-hwdb [options] update`
>
> Update the binary database.

You don't need to put this file in any `/etc/` version control, as long as you figure out when your specific distro runs `systemd-hwdb`. Search for any `systemd` units that could be generating this file at boot or at specific runtime trigger/action.

And, it's up to the distribution to choose if it will store this binary at `/etc/udev` or `/usr/lib/udev` under the name `hwdb.bin`.

Comment: Thanks. `/usr/bin/systemd-hwdb --version` works, and these files exist and contain valid definitions, so my system is "good" and I can omit this file from `etckeeper` versioning: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-hwdb-update.service` and `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hwdb-update.service`